# Query response from server when searching for id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do a really simple task: check if an inserted id matches one found in a mysql database.  If no match, an alert box will appear displaying an invalid id message.  When I run the following, the server response is:

```
SELECT * from users where id = $idnotfound
```

Any clue what might be wrong?  When a valid id is inserted, it will alert that the id is invalid, when it should do nothing.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var xhr;
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

 function callServer()
 {
 // Create the id number
 var id = document.getElementById("id").value;

 // Build the URL to connect to
 var url = "/dataExtract.php?id=" +escape(id);

 // Open a connection to the server
 xhr.open("GET", url, true);

 // Setup a function for the server to run when it is done
 xhr.onreadystatechange = idExists;

 // Send the request
 xhr.send(null);
 }

 function idExists()
 {
 if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200))
 {
var response = xhr.responseText;
if (response != 'found'){
    alert ("Invalid ID");
  return;
}
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<p>ID:<input type = "id" id="id" name="id" size="20" maxlength="40" onBlur = "callServer();"/></p>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name ="submit" value="Submit" /><br><br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php
//connect to server....

$id = $_GET["id"];

$query = 'SELECT * from users where id = $id';
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);

if (empty($result))
{
$response = "notfound";
echo $response;
}
else
{
$response = "found";
echo $response;
}


// Close connection to the database
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: <input type = "id" ??? It should be <input type="text" or some valid input type.

Comment: Fixed but I receive same response.

Comment: And is this "SELECT * from users where id = $idnotfound" is the actual output of you get? There is no place that print that sql query.

Comment: Yes, that is the actual response.  Can it be from the trigger_error?

Comment: yeah, I later saw that. See the answer below. Problem was with the single quotes in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using `$id` in a single quoted string, where it won't be evaluated. It's being interpreted literally.

You need to use double quotes for your query string. Or you could use string concatenation instead.

```
$query = "SELECT * from users where id = $id";
```

**OR**

```
$query = 'SELECT * from users where id = ' . $id;
```

Comment: Always the small things...Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because you use single quotes in query.\
'SELECT * from users where id = $id'
You should use double quotes if you need to replace the variable with the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is the single quotes in the query select statement. However, I would also suggest using JQuery on your client side. It's cleaner and handles cross-browser support for Ajax requests already. It can also be bound to the event of an element, such as a button click, separating your business code from your markup.

[JQuery ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#submitBtn').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET"
      , url: "/dataExtract.php"
      , data: {id: $('#id').val()}
      , success: function(response) {
          if(response != 'found'){
            alert('Invalid ID!');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```